# Can't compile after migrating Xamarin.Android project from package.config to csproj Package reference

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms solution.

I migrated my PCL to .net standard, worked perfectly. I then attempted to migrate my Xamarin.Android project from the package.config  setting to the new "PackageReference" setting (for Nuget) directly in csproj.

It seemed to have broken some references as I missing some System libraries: I have warning on System, System.Core, and mscorlib libraries and the path to :

Program Files (x86)- Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\

is missing in the properties of the reference.

I did everything I was used to (clean bin obj restart vs as admin etc) multiples times, with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any fix for this?

Comment: I ended up stashing all my files, re-creating the project with the right setting, and re-including all my files. I was using vs 2017 back then though, it may be smoother with vs2019